# Emails from CRM Not Threading

Tags: email, gmail, crm

I'm working on a SuiteCRM solution that will send notifications via workflows to clients.

These notifications are sent from an email address and a subject line that changes on a project basis. So "Project A Notifications" will send from "Project A Manager" with the subject "Project A"

The idea is, for every project, to have these conversations be grouped as threads in email - Gmail and elsewhere. That way, a single project could have tons of small notifications but they are all organized within the same subject line and thread. Our team could then do back and forth emails with clients while occasionally a new notification email jumps into their conversation, so all information is organized.

What I've discovered, however, is that conversations thread ONLY when emails with the same subject are sent on the same day. When I was testing this solution, I was completely convinced it would work because I had the system send tons of notification emails and did mock correspondence in the same thread with no problems. However, these tests were conducted on a single day basis.

Emails sent on different days do not thread. This crucial fact means that my tests were not at all useful.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there a possible solution that I can setup that would accomplish this (same subject, same sender, different day, same thread)?

Comment: Related, but unanswered: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vjhY4QZ3oMQ

Comment: Interessting thought: What time of day does the threading cease, and what happens on your servers at that time of day?

Comment: Another repro: also not usefully answered: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16651/112394

Comment: The second repro mentions that "Return-Path" differs, I wonder if that's including the date or some other changing info, and that causes gmail to consider it to be from a different sender, thus causing the thread to fork? Possibly the server picks a random return-path each time the process starts, and it's restarted nightly for updates?